# Can't install or boot OS, strange characters on screen

Tags: windows-7, boot, ubuntu-9.04

I reinstalled my Windows 7 and even after formatting both of my 2 HDD it still doesn't work. I get strange letters everytime Windows tries to start. Here's a photo of my screen:

[image]

So I tried to save myself by using Ubuntu which has saved me previously -- but everytime I try to start Ubuntu, even with the LIVE cd, my screen turns black with blue stripes.

Have any of you had the same problem or know if it is a virus?

Comment: does the bios show up alright? Can you ever see anything on the screen that appears normal? sounds a bit like a hardware issue, but we need a bit more info

Comment: It looks like your screen card or RAM is faulty, based on that picture.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Randolph Potter's comment.

One of the acid tests for hardware stability is "can I do a clean install of an operating system". You've done this with Windows 7 and Ubuntu so I think the answer is clear: hardware failure.

Comment: ok Yeah it almost concluded the same but dunno what, i tried to change my rams but still doesnt work anyway my video card could be the problems plz give me more replies ty

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, I'm likely going to choose graphic card issue.
Try to take off the graphic card, see if is without dust at the base,put it back, if it still does the error, you should try to find someone who can lend you a graphic card to test..

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before. I think it is probably a Graphics Card issue. I would get a new graphics card. I have heard of someone baking there graphics card to save money though. It will make the connections better and save the GPU, due to melting the connections. Look it up, but you safest and easiest bet would be to replace your graphics card.

-Good Luck. If you have any questions, please comment.